# Getting "No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language" Exception from Java code

Tags: java, plsql, jasper-reports

I have a simple report that displays fields from database. I have setup a data adapter in Jasper and put the Query. I can preview the report successfully from Jasper, but when it comes to Java it couldn't compile the report and show the following exceptions

> Jun 18, 2014 3:17:49 PM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester endElement
>   SEVERE: End event threw exception
>
> Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language.
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   Jun 18, 2014 3:17:49 PM me.jasper.print.StatementPrint generateReport
>   SEVERE: null
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 16; Error at line 7 char 16: No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language.
>
> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 16; Error at line 7 char 16: No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language.

Here is my Jasper report query setting

```
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="testDataAdapter"/>
<queryString language="plsql">
    <![CDATA[CALL getStatementDetails(250001 , "2012-01-01" , "2015-01-01" , 0 , 0)]]>
</queryString>
```

Here is my Java Code

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new File("/home/mint/JaspersoftWorkspace/MyReports/ar/plsql.jrxml"));
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<>()); 
JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(print, false);
jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the query executer factory because support for plsql is not included by default in JasperReports library. In iReport (at least in older versions), I believe this is setup for you by default. You can verify in the iReport GUI via:

- Menu Tools -> options -> Query Executers
- Specifically:

  - Language = plsql,
  - Factory Class = com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory
  - Fields Provider Class = com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.data.fieldsproviders.SQLFieldsProvider

To do the same in Java, you must do *something* like:

```
jasperReport.setProperty( "net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.plsql"
                            ,"com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory");

//Maybe this too, but not positive
JRProperties.setProperty( JRQueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX+"plsql"
                           ,"com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory");
```

Note that the class names have changed in recent versions. So, instead of `JRQueryExecuterFactory`, you might need to use `QueryExecuterFactory`. (If this does not help, you should specify which version of JasperReports you are using.)  You will also need to make sure that the JasperReports extension library is in your classpath.   You can find that jar in your iReports lib directory.

External resources:

- [JRQueryExecuterFactory](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRQueryExecuterFactory.html)
- [How to execute Oracle Stored Procedures in Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-execute-oracle-stored-procedure-jasper-report-web-application-environment)
- [No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language in JasperServer 5.1](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/no-query-executer-factory-registered-plsql-language-jasperserver-51)

Comment: Thank you. I use Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.0 and can't find query executers from GUI as you mentioned. note that the report is working properly in preview mode in Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.0 but in java it doesn't.

Comment: Jaspersoft Studio is likely similar to iReport and probably includes the PlSqlQueryExecutor configuration by default. Per my answer, you will need to do some manual configuration in code in order to run the report in Java directly.

Comment: Thank you again. that's worked. can you help on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123384/opening-new-report-jrxml-or-jasper-by-hyperlink-in-report