# Jasper Report no query executer PL/SQL in Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jasper-reports

I am new in Spring. I am using spring-mvc, PostgreSQL and iReport 5.6.0. I have a report which is running fine from iReport designer. But when I am trying to generate it from application it shows error. Here are my attempts below:

In my Jasper config:

```
<bean id="myProfilePdfReport"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
      p:url="/WEB-INF/report/ctsEmployeeProfile.jrxml"
      />
```

In my controller the URL:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET , value ="myprofile")
public ModelAndView generatePdfReport(ModelAndView modelAndView, HttpServletRequest request) {
            Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();  
            parameterMap.put("companyCode", "CTS");
            parameterMap.put("empCode", "0021");
            parameterMap.put("format", "00AA11");
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("pdfReport", parameterMap);  
            return modelAndView;     
        }
```

And finally the error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myProfilePdfReport' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jasper-view.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Could not parse JasperReports report from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/report/ctsEmployeeProfile.jrxml]; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 16; Error at line 24 char 16: No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285844

Comment: @beckyang I am doing it in another way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "No query executer factory registered for the 'plsql' language" Exception from Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285844/getting-no-query-executer-factory-registered-for-the-plsql-language-exceptio)